# Iterate through Links of the same name using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am doing a little web scraping project using Python and Selenium and I've got maybe 80% of it figured out, but I have zero web experience (and only slightly more with Selenium) so I'm not sure what I'm looking for as far as tags and elements and what not.

I'm navigating to the web page listed in my code under "driver.get" and clicking on the "View" link in the Foreclosures section. I have done that successfully with the first link (find the link using link text, click it, change window control, execute my little script to scrape data), but I don't really understand how to return from that new window and iterate to the next "View" link. I'm assuming there is some kind of unique identifier (other than "View") for each that I'm not catching onto. Basically, I need to loop through clicking on each "View" link (only in the foreclosure section) and scraping the data of the resulting pages.

I'll post the code I have which allows me to scrape the data from the first link.

Summary of what I need: 1) return from child window 2) Move to the next "View" link in page 3) Run scraping code 4) Repeat until end of Foreclosure section

Thanks in advance!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Selenium retrieve and install driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

# Navigate to page and search for "View" links to click
driver.get("http://www.hamiltoncountyherald.com/PublicNotices.aspx")
link = driver.find_element("link text", "View")
link.click()
frames = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(frames[1])

# Create list of labels of data you want to scrape
labels = ["lbl1", "lbl2", "lbl3", "lbl4", "lbl5", "lbl6", "lbl7", "lbl8", "lbl9", "lbl10", "lbl11"]

# Empty list to append data values to
list_of_data = []

# Create loop to iterate through list and print values of labels
for items in labels:
    link = driver.find_element("id", items)
    link_label = link.text
    list_of_data.append(link_label)

# Create list of titles to use as dict keys
titles = ["Borrower", "Address", "Original Trustee", "Attorney", "Instrumental No.", "Substitute Trustee", "Advertised Auction Date", "Date of First Public Notice", "Trust Date", "DR No."]

# Zip the titles and labels data together into one dict
zipped_data = dict(zip(titles, list_of_data))

# Print it out to check that it worked
for key,value in zipped_data.items():
    print(key + ":" + value)

# Quit driver
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete solution to get the data from each view link under the Foreclosure table

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "http://www.hamiltoncountyherald.com/PublicNotices.aspx"


def scrape_data():
    # Create list of labels of data you want to scrape
    labels = ["lbl1", "lbl2", "lbl3", "lbl4", "lbl5", "lbl6", "lbl7", "lbl8", "lbl9", "lbl10", "lbl11"]

    # Empty list to append data values to
    list_of_data = []

    # Create loop to iterate through list and print values of labels
    for items in labels:
        link = driver.find_element("id", items)
        link_label = link.text
        list_of_data.append(link_label)

    # Create list of titles to use as dict keys
    titles = ["Borrower", "Address", "Original Trustee", "Attorney", "Instrumental No.", "Substitute Trustee",
          "Advertised Auction Date", "Date of First Public Notice", "Trust Date", "DR No."]

    # Zip the titles and labels data together into one dict
    zipped_data = dict(zip(titles, list_of_data))

    return zipped_data


driver.get(url)
tables = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'table')[0]
foreclosure_table = tables.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'table')[7]
views = foreclosure_table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')[1:]

final_data = []
for view in views:
    # Store the current window handle
    win_handle_before = driver.current_window_handle

    # Perform the click operation that opens new window
    view.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').click()
    time.sleep(2)

    # Switch to new window opened
    for win_handle in driver.window_handles:
        driver.switch_to.window(win_handle)

    # Perform the actions on new window
    final_data.append(scrape_data())

    # Close the new window, if that window no more required
    driver.close()

    # Switch back to original browser (first window)
    driver.switch_to.window(win_handle_before)
    time.sleep(2)

print(final_data)
```

the variable "final_data" return the list of "zipped_data" from each view link in Foreclosure table.

```
[{'Borrower': 'Nancy Elizabeth Lane also known as Elizabeth Lane, formerly known as Elizabeth Jeffrey Holmes', 'Address': '710 Mystic Brook Ct', 'Original Trustee': 'Chattanooga, TN 37421', 'Attorney': 'Rocket Mortgage, LLC f/k/a Quicken Loans, LLC f/k/a Quicken Loans Inc.', 'Instrumental No.': 'Rubin Lublin TN, PLLC C/O BCNS', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 10054', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Better Choice Notice Solutions, Inc', 'Date of First Public Notice': '3/30/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/3/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'James Mayotte', 'Address': '2313 Mark Ln', 'Original Trustee': 'Chattanooga, TN 37421', 'Attorney': 'Reverse Mortgage Solutions Inc', 'Instrumental No.': 'Rubin Lublin TN, PLLC C/O BCNS', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 10112', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Better Choice Notice Solutions, Inc', 'Date of First Public Notice': '4/20/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/10/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'Melleny Andrews', 'Address': '4433 Webb Road', 'Original Trustee': 'Chattanooga, TN 37416', 'Attorney': 'Wells Fargo Bank, N.A.', 'Instrumental No.': 'Wilson & Associates, PLLC', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 10727', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Wilson & Associates, PLLC', 'Date of First Public Notice': '3/30/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/3/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'Kelsey C. Whitworth', 'Address': '114 Lavonia Avenue', 'Original Trustee': 'Chattanooga, TN 37415', 'Attorney': 'Cenlar FSB', 'Instrumental No.': 'Wilson & Associates, PLLC', 'Substitute Trustee': '', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Wilson & Associates, PLLC', 'Date of First Public Notice': '4/4/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/3/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'Jery W Howard and Mabel Howard', 'Address': '947 Ely Road', 'Original Trustee': 'Hixson, TN 37343', 'Attorney': 'Mortgage Assets Management LLC', 'Instrumental No.': 'Clear Recon', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 8420', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'BCNS/Aldridge Pite', 'Date of First Public Notice': '4/11/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/3/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'Carol Weaver', 'Address': '4319 Kemp Drive', 'Original Trustee': 'Chattanooga, TN 37411', 'Attorney': 'Amerisave Mortgage Corporation', 'Instrumental No.': 'Mackie Wolf Zientz & Mann, P.C.', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 12845', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Better Choice Notice Solutions', 'Date of First Public Notice': '4/6/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/3/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'Dereke A Silvers', 'Address': '3011 Pope Drive', 'Original Trustee': 'Chattanooga, TN 37404', 'Attorney': '', 'Instrumental No.': 'R. Houston Akin', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 11842', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Mockingbird Title & Escrow Services, LLC', 'Date of First Public Notice': '3/24/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/3/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'Amanda Swindall', 'Address': '10830 Dolly Pond Rd', 'Original Trustee': 'Ooltewah, TN 37363', 'Attorney': 'US Bank National Association', 'Instrumental No.': 'McMichael Taylor Gray', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 11482', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Better Choice Notice Solutions', 'Date of First Public Notice': '3/30/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/3/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'Tirzah Lynette Burns and James Terry Burns', 'Address': '3901 Chickamauga Avenue', 'Original Trustee': 'Chattanooga, TN 37406', 'Attorney': 'Mortgage Electronic Registration Systems Inc', 'Instrumental No.': 'James Marshall Digmon', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 10497', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Quintairos, Prieto, Wood & Boyer P.A.', 'Date of First Public Notice': '3/31/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/3/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'Sherry L. Newcomb', 'Address': '1106 Timesville Road', 'Original Trustee': 'Signal Mountain, TN 37377', 'Attorney': 'Cenlar FSB', 'Instrumental No.': 'Wilson & Associates, PLLC', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 12217', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Wilson & Associates, PLLC', 'Date of First Public Notice': '4/25/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/3/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'John James Bland Ford', 'Address': '1117 East Brow Road', 'Original Trustee': 'Lookout Mountain, TN 37350', 'Attorney': 'Geneva Financial LLC', 'Instrumental No.': 'Padgett', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 11639', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Public Notice Agency', 'Date of First Public Notice': '4/13/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/10/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'Willie J Hubbard and Connie L Hubbard', 'Address': '2915 Lightfoot Mill Rd', 'Original Trustee': 'Chattanooga, TN 37406', 'Attorney': 'Deutsche Bank National Trust Company', 'Instrumental No.': 'LLG Trustee TN LLC', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 5927', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'BCNS', 'Date of First Public Notice': '4/27/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/10/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'Margaret Shropshire', 'Address': '3729 Mark Twain Circle', 'Original Trustee': 'Chattanooga, TN 37406', 'Attorney': 'Reverse Mortgage Funding LLC', 'Instrumental No.': 'Mackie Wolf Zientz & Mann, P.C.', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 8767', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Better Choice Notice Solutions', 'Date of First Public Notice': '5/11/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/10/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'Martha Branum and Successor Trustees of the Branum Family Trust Irrev Trust Agreement', 'Address': '9319 Thrasher Trail', 'Original Trustee': 'Soddy Daisy, TN 37379', 'Attorney': 'WENDOVER PP', 'Instrumental No.': 'Mackie Wolf Zientz & Mann, P.C.', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 5688', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Better Choice Notice Solutions', 'Date of First Public Notice': '5/11/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/10/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'KEISHANNA J TEMPLETON', 'Address': '4633 PAW TRAIL', 'Original Trustee': 'Chattanooga, TN 37416', 'Attorney': 'MORTGAGE ELECTRONIC REGISTRATION SYSTEMS, INC.', 'Instrumental No.': 'Marinosci Law Group PC', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 13225', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Public Notice Agency', 'Date of First Public Notice': '4/25/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/10/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'Yvonne L. Carnes Bryant', 'Address': '2607 East 4th Street', 'Original Trustee': 'Chattanooga, TN 37404', 'Attorney': 'J.P. Morgan Mortgage Acquisition Corp', 'Instrumental No.': 'McMichael Taylor Gray', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 5846', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Better Choice Notice Solutions', 'Date of First Public Notice': '4/13/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/17/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'Pauline F Driggins', 'Address': '5704 Dagney Lane', 'Original Trustee': 'Hixson, TN 37343', 'Attorney': 'Federal Home Loan Mortgage Corporation', 'Instrumental No.': 'Padgett Law Group', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 5129', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Public Notice Agency', 'Date of First Public Notice': '4/13/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/17/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'MICHAEL R DUBSKY AND VALERIE L DUBSKY', 'Address': '917 Carrie Ln', 'Original Trustee': 'Hixson, TN 37343', 'Attorney': 'HOMETOWN LENDERS LLC', 'Instrumental No.': 'Marinosci Law Group PC', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 12891', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Public Notice Agency', 'Date of First Public Notice': '5/9/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/17/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'Herbert White Jr and Cora Patricnella H White', 'Address': '3833 ROLLINGWOOD DR', 'Original Trustee': 'Chattanooga, TN 37406', 'Attorney': 'U.S. BANK TRUST NATIONAL ASSOCIATION', 'Instrumental No.': 'BCNS RAS', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 8724', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Better Choice Notice Solutions Inc', 'Date of First Public Notice': '4/11/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/17/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'Eric S Bannister and Donya K Bannister', 'Address': '10 PAULMAR DRIVE', 'Original Trustee': 'Chattanooga, TN 37415', 'Attorney': 'Federal Home Loan Mortgage Corporation', 'Instrumental No.': 'BCNS RAS', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 7421', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Better Choice Notice Solutions Inc', 'Date of First Public Notice': '4/11/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/17/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'MARY ANN COFER HAMPTON, AKA MARY A HAMPTON A ND CARTER GRAY HAMPTON, SR., AKA CARTER G HAMPTON SR', 'Address': '824 Kay Circle', 'Original Trustee': 'Chattanooga, TN 37421', 'Attorney': 'US Bank Trust National Association', 'Instrumental No.': 'BCNS RAS', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 9324', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Better Choice Notice Solutions Inc', 'Date of First Public Notice': '4/11/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/17/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'Eva S. Long', 'Address': '814 N Germantown Rd', 'Original Trustee': 'Chattanooga, TN 37411', 'Attorney': 'Mortgage Electronic Registration Systems, Inc', 'Instrumental No.': 'Brock & Scott, PLLC', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 11658', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'C/O Tennessee Foreclosure Dept.', 'Date of First Public Notice': '5/16/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/17/2023', 'DR No.': ''}, {'Borrower': 'Melissa Jean Farrow', 'Address': '4725 NORCROSS ROAD', 'Original Trustee': 'Hixson, TN 37343', 'Attorney': 'Tennessee Housing Development Agency', 'Instrumental No.': 'Rubin Lublin TN, PLLC C/O BCNS', 'Substitute Trustee': 'GI 5452', 'Advertised Auction Date': 'Better Choice Notice Solutions, Inc', 'Date of First Public Notice': '4/27/2023', 'Trust Date': '3/17/2023', 'DR No.': ''}]
```

Hope, it's useful to you.